# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site_id_seq

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I got this error when running command `python manage.py test` for testing purpose.
I tried after delete my **pycache** and **migration** files and **db.sqlite3** then run the `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again as well.

But still got the same error...

Here is my test.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status

# Create your tests here.

class UserTest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        register_url = reverse('user:register')
        data = {
            "username":"Tester",
            "email":"tester@gmail.com",
            "password":"tester123",
            "mobile_number":"03322917356"
        }

        self.client.post(register_url, data, format='json')


    def test_user_can_register(self):
        register_url = reverse('user:register')
        data = {
            "username":"Tester1",
            "email":"tester1@gmail.com",
            "password":"tester123",
            "mobile_number":"03322911356"
        }
        response = self.clent.post(register_url , data , format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code ,status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: I've had this quite a lot, try running makemigrations with the name of the app: python3 manage.py makemigrations <app_name>. LMK ;D.

Comment: still got the same error....

Comment: try switching to postgresql, to see if it is a database issue always good to try something else. if that doesn’t work then I would get an existing example that does work and compare it from there to what you have. tbh unless you have your code opensource it is difficult to debug something like this without speculation as a lot of different systems are affected when ensuring migrations are applied. Check your migrations files to see if those are indeed correct. they should be under <app>/migrations

Comment: After switching to postgesql, now its working fine !!!

Comment: I added it as an answer, accept and close :-) perhaps once you have some time try figuring out why your sql db didn’t work, although I wouldn’t worry too much as postgres is functionally the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching to postgresql, to see if it is a database issue always good to try something else. if that doesn’t work then I would get an existing example that does work and compare it from there to what you have. tbh unless you have your code opensource it is difficult to debug something like this without speculation as a lot of different systems are affected when ensuring migrations are applied. Check your migrations files to see if those are indeed correct. they should be under /migrations

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your app in settings.py to installed apps?

In hour installed app comment out django sites. Do makemigrations and migrate. Then reactivate django sites and do the migration stuff again

Comment: Yes I already added my app in installed apps.

Comment: See my answer, django sites can be the problem

Comment: still got the same error...